# Unable to post data via HTTP POST in angular 2 on local development server

Tags: mysql, django, angular

i am new to web development and trying to get my first app working using Angular 2.  I have a reactive form from which i am building a sample invoice which has header and items information. When i try to post the data to store in DB hosted on another machine within the same network, i am getting some error on Observable operator Map stating `"[Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]/`

Here is the code :
for simplicity, i have created a variable sampleInvoice with a preformatted JSON structure that is acceptable to the server.
I have tried this data to be posted using REST extension for Chrome and it works fine.

invoice.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of }         from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions,Response, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import { Invoice, invoices } from './invoice';

    createInvoice(invoice: Invoice): Observable <Invoice>{
    let sampleInvoice = {
    "invoiceDate":"2017-03-21",
    "mobileNumber": 8297088993,
    "salesPerson": "Ramesh",
                "paymentMode": "CASH",
                "numOfItems": 1,
                "grossAmount": "2100.00",
                "totalDiscount": "200.00",
                "totalTax":"100.00",
                "netAmount": "2000.00",    
                "paidAmount": "2000.00",
                "items": [
                            {
                                "lineItem": 1,
                                "productBarcode": "product1",
                                "quantity": 1,
                                "itemGrossAmount":"1200.00",
                                "itemDiscount": "50.00",
                                "itemTax":"50.00",
                                "itemNetAmount":"1200.00"
                            },
                            {
                                "lineItem": 2,
                                "productBarcode": "product2",
                                "quantity": 2,
                                "itemGrossAmount":"400.00",
                                "itemDiscount": "50.00",
                                "itemTax":"50.00",
                                "itemNetAmount":"800.00"
                            }
        ]
    }
    let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    console.log(headers);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sampleInvoice));

    return this.http.post("http://192.168.0.9:8000/api/invoice/create/",JSON.stringify(sampleInvoice),{headers})
                              .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Note: the server (django and mySQL) is hosted on another computer at the mentioned URL.
Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Regards,
navin

Comment: I'd say most likely CORS (Cross Origin) headers are not existing on the preflight OPTIONS response from the server, therefore browser block execution of the call. 

I would first try to make the same call to a server hosted on a local machine or attempt it in no security mode of a browser (CORS disabled).

Stacktrace does not help much in such case, it would just horribly break without explanation. However somewhere in the console you should be able to see some error thrown by the browser.

Comment: @Mantas, thanks for your response. I tried using the chrome extension to disable CORS security in browser. [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) .... But no luck :(... will keep trying

Comment: @NavinHotwani You need to set the response headers in your backend as well, it's not enough to enable CORS in your browser.

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for the response. I have added the below code on the backend but no luck. .....   `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
           '192.168.0.9',  \\backend ip
           '192.168.0.13', \\client side ip
           '127.0.0.1', 
           ]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
   'localhost:4200',
   '127.0.0.1:8000',
   '192.168.0.13:4200',
   '192.168.0.9:8000'
   ]`

Comment: another thing to notice is that when i click "save" button which invokes the POST service, there is no activity on the Network tab of developer tools. I doubt if a network request is being made ?

Comment: @NavinHotwani I'm sorry, I can't help you with the backend side at all, since I don't know django. I think your post request looks pretty good.. actually you do not need to stringify the object, it goes without it. And usually we use `{headers:headers}` when doing request. Don't know if it makes any difference though, but try `return this.http.post("http://192.168.0.9:8000/api/invoice/create/",sampleInvoice,{headers:headers})`

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks for giving it a try, however that wouldn't have made a difference since i had tried that option already..... the best part is i found a solution while reading some post on how Observable works.... The issue was that i had not subscribed to the response but directly used the Catch statement.  the moment i added the subscription, it worked like charm...

Answer (score 1):

the issue turned out to be with the way i wrote Observable. What i had missed is that i did not subscribe to the response but instead used catch operator on response. Since there was no subscription, the Observable was marked as Cold and was not making any network request. here is the updated code snippet of createInvoice

```
return this.http.post(this.invoiceUrl+"create/",bodyString,options)
                          .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                          .subscribe((res)=>{
                              if (res){
                                  console.log(res);
                                  return res
                                }});
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, I didn't even think of asking if you are subscribing to the response. But great that you figured it out! :) +1 for that ;)